# Javascript not working - datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timepicker

I'm trying to use a datepicker and a time picker in my html form. My code is below :

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 50%;">
  <label>Date:</label>
  <div class="input-group date">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker" name="date" >
  </div>
  <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
<div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker3'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<label>
```

And I use the inclusions below:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

The html is working fine, I can see the datepicker field but I can't use it, the timepicker seems to got the same problem. 
When I click on it, the calendar or the timepicker are not opening.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is your javascript to initialize fields and convert to datepickers? if you only do html markup, fields know nothing about functionality.

use this:
`$('#datepicker').datepicker();`

but first! read the docs...

Comment: I use it :
   <script>
  $(function () {
  
    //Date picker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      autoclose: true
    })

    //Timepicker
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
      showInputs: false
    })
  })
</script>

Comment: I've got this : "datepicker is not a function"

Comment: where is your inclusion of datepicker itself?

Comment: This is this line right ?    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.js"></script>